# Find maximum binary number with rotations, exceed time limit

Tags: python, algorithm, suffix-array

Passed some test cases, but after submission, the time limit exceeded. How to optimize solution to reduce time complexity?

> A large binary number is represented by a string A of size N and
> comprises of 0s and 1s. You must perform a cyclic shift on this
> string. The cyclic shift operation is defined as follows:
>
> If the string A is [A0, A1,..., An-1], then after performing one
> cyclic shift, the string becomes [A1, A2,..., An-1, A0].
>
> You performed the shift infinite number of times and each time you
> recorded the value of the binary number represented by the string. The
> maximum binary number formed after performing (possibly 0) the
> operation is B. Your task is to determine the number of cyclic shifts
> that can be performed such that the value represented by the string A
> will be equal to B for the Kth time.
>
> Input format:
>
> First line: A single integer T denoting the number of test cases For
> each test case: First line: Two space-separated integers N and K
> Second line: A denoting the string
>
> Output format:
>
> For each test case, print a single line containing one integer that
> represents the number of cyclic shift operations performed such that
> the value represented by string A is equal to B for the Kth time.

```
num_test_cases = int(input())
for i in range(num_test_cases):
    array_length, num_of_repetition = map(int, input().split())

    count = 0
    bin_num = input()
    original_bin_num = bin_num
    dec_num = int(bin_num, 2)
    maximum = dec_num
    dec_num_array = [dec_num]

    for j in range(array_length - 1):
        bin_num = bin_num[1:] + bin_num[0]
        if bin_num == original_bin_num:
            break
        dec_num = int(bin_num, 2) 
        dec_num_array.append(dec_num)
    maximum = max(dec_num_array)
    maxIndex = dec_num_array.index(maximum)
    num_cyclic_shifts = 0
    for kek in range(num_of_repetition):
        if kek == 0:
            num_cyclic_shifts += maxIndex
        elif len(dec_num_array) == array_length:
            num_cyclic_shifts += array_length
        elif len(dec_num_array) < array_length:
            num_cyclic_shifts += len(dec_num_array)        
    print(num_cyclic_shifts)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation may be helpful.

Comment: These competitive-programming tasks always have a twist such that the straightforward solutions (as you did it) exceed the time limit. Hint: the biggest binary number of a given length is one of those beginning with the longest run of  '1' characters.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for optimization of your code here's how I did it.
Replace the last for loop with a formula.

```
num_cyclic_shifts = maxIndex + (len(dec_num_array) * (num_of_repetition-1))
```

Entire code will become ,

```
num_test_cases = int(input())
for i in range(num_test_cases):
    array_length, num_of_repetition = map(int, input().split())

    count = 0
    bin_num = input()
    original_bin_num = bin_num
    dec_num = int(bin_num, 2)
    maximum = dec_num
    dec_num_array = [dec_num]

    for j in range(array_length - 1):
        bin_num = bin_num[1:] + bin_num[0]
        if bin_num == original_bin_num:
            break
        dec_num = int(bin_num, 2)
        dec_num_array.append(dec_num)
    maximum = max(dec_num_array)
    maxIndex = dec_num_array.index(maximum)
    num_cyclic_shifts = maxIndex + (len(dec_num_array) * (num_of_repetition-1))
    print(num_cyclic_shifts)
```

Comment: it is indeed a nice improvement, but how did you come up with that formula? where can I get more information about it?

Comment: @Bechma solution is within that for loop. If `number_of_repetition`=0 then we can get `maxIndex` as number of shifts since cyclic shift will correspond to index. Now when `number_of_repetition`>0 we have to traverse entire `dec_num_array` ,so length of array is multiplied and added to `maxIndex`.